# CSS links annoying issue

Tags: css, hyperlink

Ok, so I've allready styled my links like so:

```
a:link{ color: red; }
a:visited{ color: red; }
a:hover{ color: blue; }
a:active{ color: red; }

a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Now I also have a footer section #footer and I want to apply different colors to the all the links inside it like so:

```
#footer a:link{ color: green; }
#footer a:visited{ color: green; }
#footer a:hover{ color: yellow; }
#footer a:active{ color: green; }
```

The problem is that I also have a link with a class of .button inside that #footer:

```
.button { color: cyan; background: gray; border: none; }
```

And the styling of the links inside the footer overrides the 'color' of my button and thus it becomes green instead of cyan.

I've placed the styling of the footer links at the bottom of my css and it didn't work.

I know I can use '!important' on the button's 'color' but I just wanted to know if there's another way around this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#footer a.button:link { color: cyan; background: gray; border: none; }
```

It will override the other styles since it's more specific. It targets any "unvisited" "a" element with class of button that is inside the element with id "footer".

CSS-tricks is a great resource of CSS and has a nice article about this: 
http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score 1):

You're running into an issue with [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

The `#footer a:link` is more specific than the `.button` rule (103 vs 10), and therefore it overrides it.

Therefore, you need a more specific rule for `button`s inside of the footer.
This could, for instance, be:

```
.button, #footer a.button:link { color: cyan; background: gray; border: none; }
```

#### See also:

- [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Answer (score 0):

The specificity isn't high enough. You could prefix `.button` with `#footer` to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path for the button:

```
#footer a.button:link { color: cyan; background: gray; border: none; }
```

Or you can also preserve both

```
.button,
#footer a.button:link { color: cyan; background: gray; border: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is a stronger selector than a class.

That's why you have to use  `#footer .button`

For instance in the markup like this

```
<div class="red" id="green">Some text</div>
```

and with the following css:

```
#green{color: green}
.red{color:red }
```

The outcome will be in green, even though class *.red* declaration comes later in the stylesheet than *#green*

Id rule can be overriten by *!important* or inline styles.

Check this on codepen [here](http://codepen.io/domkoscielak/pen/GHkEu)